# D3.geo : Spherical arcs rather than straight lines for parallels?

Tags: d3.js, topojson, d3.geo

I just made a D3js globe localisator, which looks like this :

[image]

If you look carefully, the red square looks ugly since it doesn't follow the Earth's curve. I have the area bounding box in decimal degrees :

```
var bb = {W:-5.0, N:50.0, E:10.0, S:40.0 }
```

And I draw the lines as follow:

```
svg.append("path")
.datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: 
        [[-5, 40], [-5, 50], [10, 50], [10, 40], [-5, 40]]
       })
.attr("d", path);
```

For larger areas, it's even the opposite curve from expectations (for a bounding box):

[image]

**How to add rather elegant spherical arcs ?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Given a known decimal degrees bounding box ([dig in start here for bb](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#bounds)) such as :

```
  bounds = [[-50.8,20.0][30,51.5]];
  WNES0 = bounds[0][0], // West    "W":-50.8  
  WNES1 = bounds[1][2], // North   "N": 51.5
  WNES2 = bounds[1][0], // East    "E": 30
  WNES3 = bounds[0][3], // South   "S": 20.0
```

Some maths are needed.

```
// *********** MATH TOOLKIT ********** //
function parallel(φ, λ0, λ1) {
  if (λ0 > λ1) λ1 += 360;
  var dλ = λ1 - λ0,
      step = dλ / Math.ceil(dλ);
  return d3.range(λ0, λ1 + .5 * step, step).map(function(λ) { return [normalise(λ), φ]; });
}
function normalise(x) {
  return (x + 180) % 360 - 180;
}
```

Then, let's both calculate the polygon's coordinates and project it:

```
// *********** APPEND SHAPES ********** //
svg.append("path")
.datum({type: "Polygon", coordinates: [
    [[WNES0,WNES3]]
      .concat(parallel(WNES1, WNES0, WNES2))
      .concat(parallel(WNES3, WNES0, WNES2).reverse())
  ]})
.attr("d", path)
.style({'fill': '#B10000', 'fill-opacity': 0.3, 'stroke': '#B10000', 'stroke-linejoin': 'round'})
.style({'stroke-width': 1 });
```

**180th meridian crossing:** Boxes upon the 180th meridian need special management. By example, localising a set of pacific island between 155⁰ East and -155 West initially gives....
[image]
...with correct rotation (+180⁰) :
[image]
... and with correct boxing:
[image]

Localisator now perfect ! [Live demo on blocks](http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/a62f1d61168eae985d5c)

```
var bb = { "item":"India", "W": 67.0, "N":37.5, "E": 99.0, "S": 5.0 }, 
localisator("body", 200, bb.item, bb.W, bb.N, bb.E, bb.S);
```

[image]

+1 welcome.

Answer (score 11):

You can use d3's built in [graticule generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#graticule) for this:

```
var bb = {W: -5.0, N: 50.0, E: 10.0, S: 40.0 };
var arc = d3.geo.graticule()
    .majorExtent([[bb.W, bb.S], [bb.E, bb.N]]);
```

Then use the outline function of the graticule generator to draw the path:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", path(arc.outline()));
```

[image: geographic 'arc']

Full working example can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/jsl6906/c4e61fa2ed5006b1a290).

Comment: According to documentation https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#graticule_majorExtent it needs a tiny correction.`.majorExtent([[bb.W, bb.E], [bb.N, bb.S]]);` to change into `.majorExtent([[bb.W, bb.S], [bb.E, bb.N]]);`, then it ROCKS !

Comment: (I edited the text, wait validation. Image to update)

Comment: I was unsuccessful to get the area of interest cross the 180th meridian. This case is rare but may need inspection & explorations.