# d3.js polygon strip on a cylinder spanning more than 360°

Tags: d3.js, projection

Following this question,

[D3.geo : Spherical arcs rather than straight lines for parallels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415885/d3-geo-spherical-arcs-rather-than-straight-lines-for-parallels)

I was able to draw projected polygons (1) by using `path`:

```
var poligono = {                                                                                                                      
"type": "Polygon",                                                                                                                
"coordinates": [                                                                   
    [[0, 0], [0, 20], [100, 20], [100, 0], [0, 0]]                                                              
  ]
}

 // [...]                                                                                                                                     

   svg.append("path")                                                                                                                  
  .attr("class", "arc")                                                                                                               
  .attr("d", path(poligono));
```

and unprojected rectangles (2) using `.outline()`:

```
  var arc = d3.geoGraticule()                                                                                                         
 .extentMajor([[0, 0], [-20, -20]])          

     // [...]                                                                                                                                     


  svg.append("path")                                                                                                                  
  .attr("class", "arc")                                                                                                               
  .attr("d", path(arc.outline()));
```

What is the best way to draw a polygon such as the blue one in the figure (3), i.e. an unprojected polygon enrolling the cylinder for more than 360°?

[image: unprojecgted example]

(The general goal is to draw this kind of surfaces on a generic cylinder, and not specifically on a geographic projection)